# Is there any "Built in function to Concatenate the whole NSMutableArray NSString items"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsmutablearray

is there any built in function to Concatenate the whole NSMutableArray NSString items

i have an NSMutableArray with 4 elements in the following structure

```
myArray[0] = "HI";
myArray[1] = "WELCOME";
myArray[2] = "TO";
myArray[3] = "STACKOVERFLOW";
```

I need to get the sentence "HI WELCOME TO STACKOVERFLOW" from my NSMutableArray(myArray) .

may i know , any built in functions to do it?

Thanks

NB:Without iterating the array through any loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's function you need:

```
 NSString *result = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do `NSString *myString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];`